# Which webhook to listen to confirm payout recieved by external bank account in stripe

Tags: stripe-payments

i am using stripe connet account, and i need to transfer money from platform balance to my connected user's external bank account..

so i am using transfers api . on using transfer api, amount is deducted from platform balance and added to connected user's transfers..

after scheduled payout timing.. i.e. (2 days for US) after the transfer was made, the payout will be attempted..

now i want to get notified when the amount reaches the user's bank account... what webhook i should use?

will only transfer(transfer.paid, transfer.failed) webhook will be enough or i need to use payout(payout.failed, payout.paid) webhooks also to be used to get notification that amount reached my connected user's external bank account.

Answer (score 0):

You'll receive a [`payout.paid`](https://stripe.com/docs/api/events/types#event_types-payout.paid) event when Stripe expects the payout to land; however, Stripe doesn't receive confirmation of it, so it's a best guess.  If the payout fails, you'll receive a `payout.failed`, so as long as you don't receive that one, you should be good.

Comment: but as i am using transfer api to send money from platform balance to connect account, i get a transfer id, so i will not able to track a payout webhook, which has only payout id..

Comment: Yup, you use Transfer, but Stripe pays out via Payout - so if you want to know about the payouts, you'll have to listen to the Payout events.

Comment: i am unable to get the payout details of a connect account by using platform secretkey in the api.. the support team said.. only by using a particular connect account's secret key i can access its payout details..

Comment: You would need to use both your Platform Secret Key and the Stripe Account header: https://stripe.com/docs/connect/authentication#stripe-account-header